# How to get generation count of parent-child relation

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I've a table like this:

```
ID    Person    ParentID
1     P1        0
2     P2        1
3     P3        1
4     P4        0
5     P5        4
6     P6        4
7     P7        4
8     P8        3
9     P9        3
10    P10       6
11    P11       7
```

So, these has relations like as below :

```
P1
  -> P2
  -> P3
       -> P8
       -> P9
P4
  -> P5
  -> P6
       -> P10
  -> P7
       -> P11

P1,P4(parents)
P2,P3,P5,P6,P7(children)
P8,P9,P10,P11(grandchildren)
```

There are 3 generations in this relationship. How can I find this in sql?

[image]

Comment: please post your expected output format

Comment: I expected number of 3. I only need 3 (the generation number)

Comment: so you want count of generations

Comment: yes, I want count of generations

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group first the children of each elements and them create some recursive method to get the levels:

```
var query= context.People.GroupBy(p=>p.ParentId ?? 0);//In case ParentId is null, by default this element is going to be a root.
var roots= query.FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Key==0);

int max=0;
foreach(var p in roots)
{
   var temp=GetLevels(1, p, query);
   if(temp>max)
   {
     max=temp;
   }
}
```

This could be the recursive method:

```
public int GetLevels(int level,Person current, IQueryable<IGrouping<int,Person>> groups)
{
        var g = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == current.Id);
        if(g==null)
        {
            return level;
        }
        int max = level;
        foreach (var child in g)
        {
           int currentLevel= GetLevels(level + 1, child, groups);
            if (currentLevel>max)
            {
                max = currentLevel;
            }
        }
        return max;
}
```

Comment: I get error for "query" parameter in GetLevels method call.

Comment: could you give more details about it?Your `ParentId` is an integer, right?

Comment: Yes. It is integer. I get this error : http://i.hizliresim.com/y46vWa.png

Comment: yes it's an integer but that column can be `null`, that's why your key is a nullable int (`int?`) instead an int. I'm going to update my answer